# php preg_match_all between ... and

Tags: php, preg-match-all

I'm trying to use `preg_match_all` to match anything between `...` and `...` and the line does word wrap. I've done number of searches on google and tried different combinations and nothing is working. I have tried this

```
preg_match_all('/...(.*).../m/', $rawdata, $m);
```

Below is an example of what the format will look like:

```
...this is a test...

...this is a test this is a test this is a test this is a test this is a test this is a test this is a test this is a test this is a test...
```

Answer (score 1):

The `s` modifier allows for `.` to include new line characters so try:

```
preg_match_all('/\.{3}(.*?)\.{3}/s', $rawdata, $m);
```

The `m` modifier you were using is so the `^$` acts on a per line basis rather than per string (since you don't have `^$` doesn't make sense).

You can read more about the modifiers [here](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php).

Note the `.` needs to be escaped as well because it is a special character meaning `any character`. The `?` after the `.*` makes it non-greedy so it will match the first `...` that is found. The `{3}` says three of the previous character.

Regex101 demo: https://regex101.com/r/eO6iD1/1

Answer (score 0):

Please escape the literal dots, since the character is also a regular expressions reservered sign, as you use it inside your code yourself:

```
preg_match_all('/\.\.\.(.*)\.\.\./m/', $rawdata, $m)
```

In case what you wanted to state is that there are line breaks within the content to match you would have to add this explicitely to your code:

```
preg_match_all('/\.\.\.([.\n\r]*)\.\.\./m/', $rawdata, $m)
```

Check here for reference on what characters the dot includes:
http://www.regular-expressions.info/dot.html

Answer (score 0):

You're almost near to get it,

so you need to update your `RE`

```
/\.{3}(.*)\.{3}/m
```

**RE breakdown**

`/`: start/end of string

`\.`: match `.`

`{3}`: match exactly 3(in this case match exactly 3 dots)

`(.*)`: match anything that comes after the first match(`...`)

`m`: match strings that are over Multi lines.

and when you're putting all things together, you'll have this

```
$str = "...this is a test...";
preg_match_all('/\.{3}(.*)\.{3}/m', $str, $m);
print_r($m);
```

outputs

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => ...this is a test...
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => this is a test
        )

)
```

**[DEMO](http://ideone.com/WXMCZj)**